# Restore SiteCollection SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Im using SharePoint 2013. Im wondering how to get rid of an orphan database. I tried the following stsadm -o deletesite -force -SiteID ********************* -DatebaseName ContentDB_Matt -DatabaseServer SQL_Instance
http://sharepoint-mattharmon.blogspot.com/2015/09/deleting-orphaned-sites-from-sharepoint.html however it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I dealt with an orphaned site was during a restore.  I had to Unmount and re-Mount the content database.  This process seems to resolve the issue that is causing the site to be incorrectly flagged as an orphaned site.

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://<your sp site>/<orphaned site collection>
$contentDB = $site.ContentDatabase
Dismount-SPContentDatabase -Identity $contentDB.Id
Mount-SPContentDatabase “<your content database name>” -DatabaseServer <your sql alias> -WebApplication http://<your sp site>
```